# Variable inside a byte string to change dynamically

Tags: python, byte

I have this byte string `"\x02\x09\x88"` in python.

How can i change that 88 dynamically?

I tried:

```
sts = bytes('\x02\x09\x{}'.format("88"), 'ascii')
```

i get the error unicodeescape codec cant decode bytes in position 8-9: truncated \nXX escape

But with no luck, i cant figure it out.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the byte string in two parts.  If your string is in the form '88' use int(s, 16) to convert it:

```
dynamic_part = '88'
byte_element = int(dynamic_part, 16)
sts = b'\x02\x09' + bytes([byte_element])
print(sts)
```

which prints:

```
b'\x02\t\x88'
```

Comment: IT will not always be an INT sometimes its EA

Comment: what is EA?  is that a data type?

Comment: It will all be HEX values